# How to remove the banner on map control in on-premises version?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I've installed on-premisses 2013 and just noticed that the map control has a banner in the middle telling me that "*the specified credentials are invalid*". I don't want to use my own LiveID to register.

What's the best work-around?

There's a [blog on the subject](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dynamicspts/archive/2013/11/08/setting-up-bing-maps-with-dynamics-crm-2013-on-premise.aspx) but I want to skip the LiveID-based license part because it needs to be renewed every three month or something.

Comment: You need the Basic key, not the Trial key, to avoid the 90 day limit. The issue is I've never seen clarification on what the correct licensing is for using Bing Maps in Dynamics CRM. From my reading, you need to purchase a Bing API Enterprise License or you'll be in violation of the license agreement. For Dev/Test you can use a Trial or Basic license.

Comment: Please post it as a reply, preferably with some links or something, so I can accept that as an answer.